# Ensure to only get rows belonging to the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

This is quite hard for me to explain but I try to do my best.

I have an application with multiple users with logins. These users can have some employees attached to them. I wish to avoid users viewing/editing other employees that does not belong to them.

I have a **User** class like so:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(int userid)
    {
        //
        // Gets the user from the database and fills the properties
        //
    }
}
```

And a **Employee** class like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
    }

    public Employee(int employeeid)
    {
        //
        // Gets the employee from the database and fills the properties
        //
    }
}
```

The problem in this is like when I edit an employee the querystring in the application can be like:

> ~/EditEmployee.aspx?id=1

Where the `id` is the `ID` of the employee. By quickly editing this `ID` I can be lucky to fetch an employee that does not belong to the current user logged in.

While this can be solved by having a

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int id) 
{
    // Gets the employee (using this.ID as UserID) from the database
}
```

method on the `User` object, that supplies the stored procedure with the `User.ID` property and checking up with:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND UserID = @UserID
```

But with this I ALWAYS have to create an instance of the `User` object to get an employee.

This makes the `Employee(int id)` on the `Employee` object obsolete.

*Is there not any other way around?*

The question for this is that I am in the situation where I do not want to make an instance of the User object to get an employee because I am 100% sure I have the right employee ID. (To avoid too many database calls).

Do I really have to keep the `Employee(int id)` on the `Employee` object and create a new stored procedure that does not check up on `UserID`?

This example is fictive. Best way to explain it than pasting hundreds of lines of code and object. Maybe I am too much of a performance freak. But I just wish to improve my way of doing multiple user sites.

I really hope this will explain it well, I tried my best. :-)

Comment: have you considered the case of an administrator?

Comment: what if an admin needs to edit the user?

Comment: To me it sounds like you want to implement something like roles, or groups. Is that a correct observation?

Comment: Have you considered using session object to store current user object  and when ever you need current user object you just get if from your session object

Comment: The user is the "admin" - The user logs in and edits the employee belonging to the user. Maybe I have not explained it very well.

Comment: Emmanuel, that could maybe to it. hmm....

Comment: I would not recommend performing a database call in your constructors. Take a look at the Repository or ActiveRecord patterns for better data access.

Comment: Are you saying that if someone edits the `ID` in the query string they can see the employee they want, but you're check for the current user also, but that makes the `public Employee(int employeeid)` method useless?

Comment: Correct giddy, that I wrote on the post aswell. I will have to make the User first and then getting the employee from the user object.

Comment: @Eoin Campbell solution will do it for you

Comment: Authenticate the user with a password, set up a session, restrict access to the user ID specified in the session. This is login-based systems 101.

Comment: I agree with @jrummell the persistence of your entities should not be handled in the constructor. You have already shown that you may want to load the entities differently given different contexts. If you must do this in the constructor I would personally use dependency injection and offload the persistence to another object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most basic issue here meep is that you are mixing your code/object instantiation with your DataAccess.

I would suggest that you seperate the two.  Don't use the Constructor of the object as a way of retrieving data from your database. Have a seperate DataAccess layer that performs the queries, and then Hydrates your Employee Object.

if the employee data can only be retrieved in the context of the Current User, then you need to:
a) Keep that userId available during your web session
b) pass that userId to every database query as a filter to make sure only the correct data is returned.

- So just create the `User` object once at the start. (i.e. when they login)
- Put that `User` object into Session/Cache
- Everytime you go to the database, pass that UserId as well as the EmployeeId to the Query.

**Edit**

Just to emphasize, I wasn't suggested mixing session vars into your DataAccess.
You could have some property on your Page/BasePage for storing the user Object in session. e.g.

```
public User CurrentUser {
    get { 
        return Session["CurrentUser"] != null ?
            (User) Session["CurrentUser"] :
            null;
    }
    set { Session["CurrentUser"] = value; }
}
```

You would populate that object with the User Object when the user logs in. Then you can go back and get it at any time. e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var empId = //Code to get it from Query String.
     var userId = this.CurrentUser.UserId;
     Employee e = DataAccess.GetEmployee(empId, userId);
     if(e != null) 
         //Do funky stuff
}
```

Comment: Maybe storing the UserID in the session will do this aswell. I just dont like passing session variables in the database calls.

Comment: well you definitely shouldn't "embed" the session variable in the database call... I'll edit in some code above

Comment: @meep Is there a particular reason you don't like using Session variables in your database queries? There's nothing wrong with it and it's often very helpful! Ninja edit (inspired by Eoin Campbell's comment): As long as you are using variables and not concatenation to build your queries, that is.

Comment: Guess I will have to supply both userid and employee id to be sure then

Comment: @EoinCampbell, what if I should use the "User" in an .cs file? How should I get the instance?

Answer (score 1):

I'm purposely excluding any mention of roles, permissions, etc.. Here is a simple approach (perhaps).

Instead of passing a raw row ID into the query string I'd use a GUID or other unique ID that would represent an employee and pass that instead. This way it couldn't be guessed. You could also then have a list of employees id's (not the raw ID) contained in your user class that you could test against, if the user wants to view an employee you then check the query string ID to see the user is authorized to view that employee based on it's internal representation of employee id's.

Comment: You could guess GUIDs, it would just take a lot longer. Security through obscurity is not a great way to go. And personally I prefer standard ints for IDs since I can then remember commonly used userIDs like admin when I'm debugging things.

Comment: Yes security is another matter indeed.

Answer (score 0):

OK so from the comments your worried about someone editing the query string. I like @Frank's suggestion but..

You can just authenticate the request first, then display the page! Check and see if the user is logged in with a session object, then only you display the page.

And then maybe change your method to:

```
public Employee GetEmployeeForUser(int employeeid, int userId)
{
}
```

So you get the right employees.

Maybe you're over-optimizing/thinking on the correctness of your design and/or performance.  It doesn't matter sometimes where you place trivial methods, make the app work, then you can re-factor and performance tune later.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not supply the UserID to the EditEmployee.aspx page as well? Something like ~/EditEmployee.aspx?id=1 with a Session variable containing the User ID? You must have some way of knowing what the UserID is when a user visits the EditEmployee.aspx page (as otherwise how would you know whether or not that Employee belongs to that User?).

Since you must have some way to know that information, why not modify your constructor to include UserID as well? I would argue that doing so is perfectly valid, seeing as how your `Employee` class requires some information about the `User` class before deciding whether or not it's "allowed" to load data...

Perhaps something like this?

```
public class Employee
{
    // .... other things

    public Employee(int userid, int employeeid)
    {
        //
        // Gets the employee from the database and fills the properties
        //
        //SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND UserID = @UserID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You presumably have some way of knowing who the currently logged in user is. This could be anything from a full user object to a userid or username stored in your session.

I would then suggest a factory method of some kind to get employees (similar to your example but not on the user object) necessarily. This method can do security checks and throw an appropriate security exception (or whatever) if the currently logged on user doesn't in fact have access to that employee.

The bottom line is that you have to at some point look at the userid and the employeeid together to work out if permission is granted. The key thing is you don't need a full object necessarily, just a small piece of identifying information.